# Finding Downloaded APK files in nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, apk

I have a unrooted nexus 5 and i want to analyze google play downloaded app source code but i cannot find any of my apps when i connect my phone to the computer...
any one know how can i:

1. Save google play app without extracting the apk file...
2. finding the app when connecting in to computer.
3. check the app source code in the computer

the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ignite.lottosheli

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to look at the source code of a lottery app?

Answer (score 0):

Achieving your request (*"check the app source code"*) is simply not possible since an APK doesn't contains any source code, only Java bytecode and/or native compiled code for different processors architectures.

More details here: [Android application package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package)